# Azure Logic Apps - Failed with error: 'The browser is closed.'. Please sign in again

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I have created an Azure Logic App in the Azure portal and successfully added several steps.  I add the Azure DevOps List Iterations step and click the sign-in button.  A popup prompts me to sign-in and then closes and I am left with the follow error in the Logic Apps designer:

Failed with error: 'The browser is closed.'. Please sign in again.

[image]

I have am recreating a workflow that I originally created using Microsoft Power Automate (Flow) so I know that my credentials should work.

Now when I hit the sign-in again I do not get the option to re-enter any credentials nor change accounts.

Comment: This error usually occurs you close the authorization page without accepting the authorization. Please accept the authorization. Also, check the login account to see whether it is the correct account.

Answer (score 24):

What fixed it for me was allowing 3rd party cookies:

- In your browser settings, make sure that you **allow all cookies** (including 3rd party cookies: a lot of Microsoft webapps depend on that),
- Refresh the Logic App page (might not be required, but it doesn't hurt),
- Add a new connection and sign in.

You can then block 3rd party cookies again after this if you wish.

Comment: Thanks. I had to disable 3rd party cookie blocking temporary in Firefox Tracking Protection settings.

Comment: This worked for me too - I was using Incognito mode in Chrome which doesn't by default allow 3rd party cookies. After changing this setting it worked as expected.

Comment: Chrome was blocking a cookie from ema.hosting.portal.azure.net. Allowing this cookie fixed the issue

Answer (score 4):

for me change browser from Chrome to MS Edge beta helped

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, please check the resource group which your logic app belongs to. When you click the "Sign in" first time, it will generate a "API Connection" in the same resource group of you logic app. Its name should be like "visualstudioteamservices" (shown as below screenshot).

[image]

Please delete this api connection and then wait a few minutes(because there may be a delay in deleting operation). Then go back to your logic app and delete the DevOps List Iterations action, then create the DevOps List Iterations action again it will ask you for the sign in credential.

By the way, if your browser remember the last credential, it may still have some problem. Please delete the api connection and change to another browser to have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Open an incognito/private window in your browser, then attempt to create the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the exact same issue, thought it had to do with my subscription being free trial.

But it logged in perfectly once I switched from Safari to Chrome (on a MacOS 11.2).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Firefox to create a Logic App, solved by turning off Enhanced Tracking Protection for portal.azure.com

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing of the location of the logic app helped.

**North Europe > West Europe**

Browser: Edge